# how to add count column with join?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have run this query to join between two table and that was ok

```
SELECT 
TaskName AS TaskStatusTitle,
COUNT(TblTask.UserID),
CreateDate,
UserID,
TblProfiles.FullName AS [User Full Name] 
FROM Task.TblTask
RIGHT JOIN Users.TblProfiles 
ON Task.TblTask.UserID=Users.TblProfiles.UserrId
GROUP BY UserID`
```

but then i added count to this query but i gave this error!
what should i do??

Column 'Task.TblTask.TaskName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Can you please update this question to contain both the old query that ran correctly, and also the new query that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using MySQLor MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Why RIGHT JOIN?!? Switch to LEFT JOIN instead, since most people find "main table left join optiona data" much easier to understand than "option data right join main table".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all the columns into the group by clause when using an aggregate function. Like this

```
SELECT 
TaskName AS TaskStatusTitle,
COUNT(TblTask.UserID),
CreateDate,
UserID,
TblProfiles.FullName AS [User Full Name] 
FROM Task.TblTask
RIGHT JOIN Users.TblProfiles 
ON Task.TblTask.UserID=Users.TblProfiles.UserrId
GROUP BY 
UserID,TaskName ,CreateDate,    TblProfiles.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need every column, which you are selecting in group by clause.

```
SELECT 
TaskName AS TaskStatusTitle,
COUNT(TblTask.UserID),
CreateDate,
UserID,
TblProfiles.FullName AS [User Full Name] 
FROM Task.TblTask
RIGHT JOIN Users.TblProfiles 
ON Task.TblTask.UserID=Users.TblProfiles.UserrId
GROUP BY UserID,TaskName,CreateDate,TblProfiles.FullName
```

Comment: Duplicate answer!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on aggregate functions with group by clause, make sure that you have included all the columns into group by clause also.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
TaskName AS TaskStatusTitle,
COUNT(TblTask.UserID),
CreateDate,
TblTask.UserID,
TblProfiles.FullName AS [User Full Name] 
FROM Task.TblTask
RIGHT JOIN Users.TblProfiles 
ON Task.TblTask.UserID=Users.TblProfiles.UserrId
GROUP BY TaskName,CreateDate,TblTask.UserID,TblProfiles.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TaskName AS TaskStatusTitle,
COUNT(TblTask.UserID)OVER(PARTITION BY UserID) AS CNT ,
CreateDate,
UserID,
TblProfiles.FullName AS [User Full Name] 
FROM Task.TblTask
RIGHT JOIN Users.TblProfiles 
ON Task.TblTask.UserID=Users.TblProfiles.UserrId
```